# ¿Cómo puedo codificar una función que calcule el largo de una palabra de forma recursiva?

Tags: python

quisiera ver la posibilidad que me pudieran ayudar con un problemita en python, es que me esta dando dolores de cabeza y no lo he podido resolver, si me pudieran ayudar por favor

[image]

Tengo un poco de código pero esta malo :( lo adjunto de todas maneras.

```py
def largo(palabra):
    if len(palabra)==0:
        return 0
    elif len(palabra)==1:
        return 1
    elif len(palabra)%2==0:
        return 2*largo(int(len(palabra))/2)
    else:
        return 2*largo(int(len(palabra))/2)+1
```

De ante mano muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Para que te ayuden con mas facilidad, coloca el código no como imagen sino como un bloque de código(texto)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, tu pregunta esta casi bien planteada, si bien dices que tu código es malo no dices el por qué, que pasa con tu código? te da error? no hace lo que esperas? Debes añadir más detalles a tu pregunta. Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/503245/edit) tu pregunta las veces que quieras. Por último te recomiendo leer [ask] para que sepas como plantear tu pregunta y utilizar las etiquetas apropiadas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código de la imagen es exageradamente redundante y poco óptimo.
Se puede realizar una función recursiva para resolver el problema:

Definimos la variable que almacenará la palabra: `palabra = "Anabelle"`

Ahora que ya tenemos la variable, tendremos que definir una función que condicionará dos cosas:

> La primera es que si no hay palabra, retorna 0, resuelve la operación
> con 0, lo cual nos imprime en blanco.
>
> La segunda es que si hay una palabra, cuenta la longitud de dicha
> palabra con un contador y con el posicionamiento de caracteres.

Una vez que nos retorna un número, resuelve la operación y realiza una división entera `//` para que no nos arroje decimales y nos imprime dicho número para posicionarlo con el posicionamiento de caracteres en la variable `palabra`:

```
def largo(palabra) :
     
    if palabra == '':
        return 0
    else :
        return 1 + largo(palabra[1:])
 
a=int(largo(palabra))//2

print(palabra[:a])
```

**Bonus:**

Tendrás que pensar dónde poner la segunda parte de tu código:

```
if largo(palabra) % 2 == 0:
    print(f'La palabra {palabra} es par')
else:
    print(f'La palabra {palabra} es impar')
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias me quedo claro

Comment: Hice una modificación al código, dale una revisada

Comment: La recursividad nunca es buena y es mejor optar por 9tras soluciones

Comment: Pero ahí dice "resolver de forma recursiva" y es lo que le piden en el ejercicio, supongo para que aprenda a realizar recursividad ¯\_O_O_/¯

Comment: pues sip, pero yo mostraría otra forma, no importa igual tu solución esta bien. Pero recuerda evitar responder a preguntas de baja calidad, lo mejor es guiar al usuario a plantear una buena pregunta y así mantener la calidad del sitio :D

Comment: @carlosbianchi la forma de decir gracias aquí es marcar la respuesta como aceptada (un check abajo de los votos) esto recompensa a ambos :D.